# Checking a box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check a box using jQuery. I've looked at some of the answers on this site but none of them worked (or I'm doing it wrong).

Here is the DOM

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ckbx_81861252,uFT1" name="memberIds" class="memberIds" value="81861752,uGT2">
```

When I click the box on the page, I don't see anything being updated in the DOM. Can anyone explain why? Or maybe I'm just missing it?

I tried both using `.prop` & `.attr` but neither checked the box.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: share the code you tried??

Comment: If you click on the checkbox it should automatically toggle its checked state...you don't need jquery or javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the checkbox it should automatically toggle its checked state. If you want it with jQuery then try:

- **To check:** `$('input[name="memberIds"]').prop('checked', true);`
- **To Uncheck:** `$('input[name="memberIds"]').prop('checked', false);`

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong before, but this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

its probably your comma. You have to escape it.

```
    $('#ckbx_81861252\\,uFT1').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having issues because of your id:

[Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/mxwwr4uz/)

[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/2ya32gka/1/)

Look at both fiddles and notice the difference is the id...

Try a different ID:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="memberIds">
```